# SMTP simple Gmail C#

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I want to send an email from C# using Gmail. To test this I'm running a simple console project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;


namespace MailTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            //UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myMail@gmail.com",     "StrongPassword123"),
            EnableSsl = true
        };
        client.Send("myMail@gmail.com", "myMail@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
}
```

This gives me the following error:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

What I have tried so far:
Change my gmail password to a stronger one.
Configured my McAfee antivirus to not block mass mail worms:
My antivirus logs the following line when I try to run the project:
10/31/2014  10:31:13 AM Would be blocked by port blocking rule  (rule is currently not enforced)    \srv-be-file.vasco.com\UserProfiles$\kiekema1\Documents\Travel Request Portaal\MailTest\MailTest\bin\Debug\MailTest.vshost.exe Anti-virus Standard Protection:Prevent mass mailing worms from sending mail 74.125.136.108:587

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Try yo set `DelivierMethod`: `client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;`

Comment: Also try setting `UseDefaultCredentials = false` for the SmtpClient

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. You don't need to set DeliveryMethod or UseDefaultCredentials. Make sure you have configured your Gmail to allow "less secure apps" to connect. (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

Comment: Still gives me the same SMTPException.

Comment: Yes, I have that configuration, Johan.

Comment: My guess would be a network issue, then. I even compiled and ran your code and it works on my machine[TM].

Comment: I also tried a Telnet test: telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 and it gives no errors.